# how to query inside SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy for my app and I have this kind of model

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Projects'

    idProject = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('seqproject'::regclass)"))   
    idCompany = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('Company.idCompany'), nullable=False, index=True)  
    Company = db.relationship('Company')
```

And same model for Company only with ID and name...

What I want to do is to get Company name and not idCompany (or both) so I want to do something like

```
CompanyName = Company.name
```

But it doesn't work ..but what does work is

```
user = User.query.filter(User.mail.ilike('jeneva.garry0@mts.net')).first()
projects = user.projects
return status(projects[0].Company.name)
```

status returns `{"status": "nameOfTheCompany"}`

Thanks for the help

Comment: please check that your naming is PEP8 compliant; the attribute name `company` should be in lower case. Perhaps you'd want to use a [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-transformers) for `company_name`

Comment: cant you just do `Company.query.all()`, I mean as u already have a `company` model you can use it directly.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  I will

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI in the model ? I just tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: could you add the `company` model as well in the question

Comment: [link to the model on paste2.org](http://paste2.org/52KNfP2Y)

Comment: are you calling the `Company` model outside the `@app.route` method? if so then you might need to write `with app.app_context()` (i.e context manager ) as all sqlalchemy ( in flask-sqlalchemy) need `app_context` .

Comment: Thank you I already solved it  ..really simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it like this

in model Project I just did this :) stupid me.

```
 def toJson(self):
    return jsonify(number=self.number,
               message=self.message,
               name=self.name,
               comment=self.comment,
               CompanyName=self.company.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the model you can specify the relation between Company and Project wont behave as list

```
company = db.relationship('Company',uselist=False,foreign_keys='Project.idCompany')
```

Then you can do

```
proyect = Proyect.query.first()
proyect.company.name
```